# How to structure an academic paper using basic statistical techniques?

Tags: publications, writing-style

I am teaching a class on introduction to academic research.  The papers that I've written have mostly been according to a style that I "just picked up" from reading academic papers, and most of these were CS/math type affairs that involved a lot of *theory* and not much *science*.

**Is there a common formula for structuring a paper that involves collecting and analyzing data with basic intro-statistics techniques (inferences about a mean, univariate OLS regression, etc)?**  Examples of well-written papers comprehensible to a broad audience illustrating these guiding principles welcome.

Comment: Scan through a few papers in, say, sociology, education, or medical research. Ask a colleague for examples and then discuss the structure with them.

Comment: @Buffy "a few papers" Surely you jest.  In my experience, the vast majority of papers in any given field are deep with jargon and also frequently involve, e.g. multiple ANOVA (med) or structured equation models (psych).  The probability that an arbitrary paper will be a good exemplar for introductory purposes is low....

Comment: No, just a scan for the structure. You don't need the detail, just the overall outline. That was your question after all. In the social sciences, which use a lot of statistical methods, the structure is pretty common.

Comment: @Buffy "just the overall outline" if by overall outline, you mean just the section titles, then this isn't generally super informative.  Just as an example, [here is a search for "one-sided t test mean"](https://www.nature.com/search?q=one-sided%20t%20test%20mean&order=relevance) in Nature.  It's pretty apparent from just the titles and blurbs that none of these will be comprehensible to anyone outside of the field.  "What sort of thing goes in a Methodology section?"  This is not answerable using these examples.

Comment: Methodology: What is the population of interest? How will you gather the data (ethically, for some studies). Sample sizes. What statistical tests will you use. What criteria for acceptance. How will you deal with problems of, say, data collection.

Comment: @Buffy, what about "statement of hypotheses"?  "Assertion that hypotheses are not post-hoc".  Is it common to "discuss the meaning of our $p$-value and the effect size in the context of the problem at hand"?, or maybe "why is the t-test (or whatever) appropriate for this analysis".  If you were to expand on your most recent comment, I could be convinced to accept such an answer.

Comment: Actually, I'm not convinced that the question is really on topic here. See the [answer of The_Tams](https://academia.stackexchange.com/a/183383/75368) which is pretty accurate. I think your downvotes come from a feeling that you didn't do your homework before you asked here. This is pretty standard stuff. There are books on research methodology, for example.

Comment: @Buffy is "must read textbook" generally a prerequisite for questions on this site?

Comment: @Buffy The Tams answer is not very informative.  "Methodology == How we collected and analyzed the data" is so broad as to be vacuous.  Surely there are guiding principles for "how to describe the data collection and analysis process"?  You yourself have pointed out a few that are not included in TheTams answer, such as "identifying the population of interest".

Comment: Possibly my question has been phrased in such a way as to elicit such broad answers.  I am more interested in structures for how to describe the details of the process of good science in a report.  Do you have any suggestions for improving my question?

Answer (score 1):

Style will depend on your their field. There is no one style across academia. In science, the most common structure is the following:

1. Introduction - what we already know and where is the gap/issue we
   are addressing. The question you intend to answer and hypotheses
   (if hypothesis driven) are also in this section, usually toward
   the end.
2. Methods - how we collected and analysed the data,
   where it came from, including statistical methods. Aka 'why you
   should believe my results'.
3. Results - the output, often
   statistically interpreted but not "what it means".
4. Discussion - what we think it means bringing together the intro,
   methods, and results to make an argument. How it addresses the
   gap/issue/questions from the introduction. If relevant, was the
   hypothesis supported or not.

The complexity or simplicity of the tools used (statistical or otherwise) doesn't change the overall structure.

Comment: Actually, you miss an important part: The question(s) to be answered by the research. Normally research is directed toward some end. You need to make that specific. And it is important enough to separate out. Generally, the hypotheses, and the criteria for acceptance/rejection though the latter might be part of Methods.

Comment: I considered that is included the gap/issue I am addressing, but happy to edit to make that explicit if you like. Not all science is hypothesis driven though. It may be out of fashion, but some of us are still publishing descriptive work.

Comment: It's a pretty big deal.

Comment: Since a lot of such research results in somewhat tentative conclusions, there is often a section on "Further Work" or "Next Steps". Statistical work results in evidence for a hypothesis, not truth in, say, the mathematical sense. Samples represent populations only imperfectly.

Answer (score 0):

For structuring the paper specifically - no, I do not believe it is the case. The overall structure of the paper is common (and described by The_Tams), section titles themselves vary from journal to journal.

Importantly, the techniques used and statistical tools are not universal, either - in social sciences, a p-value of .05 is still considered "good enough", while in HEP a threshold of 5 sigma is the Holy Grail. This is why there is a separate course (or several!) in statistics, on what techniques to employ, how and when. Sometimes, answers to those questions get very in-depth, so it is most likely outside the scope of what you are teaching. I would even argue that a blanket "use the t-test because 87% of papers in the field do so" is actively harmful. They should be made familiar with the tools of the trade, but in more detail and most certainly not on a "how to do research" kind of course.

You could do your students a service, however, by showing them a "hands-on" approach of how would one start working on a paper in any given journal, showcasing your thought process while reading the "Information for Authors" and eventually mocking up the entire paper with some imaginary "results".

Comment: "mocking up the entire paper" I would rather have them read some accessible papers that do a good job of following the scientific method formula, possibly from different fields.  Things like "meticulously plan the experimental design BEFORE gathering data" are universally sound design decisions that span disciplines.  "Ensure that your plan for data collection will satisfy the assumptions of the statistical test that you plan to use.", etc.  I am aware of many of these caveats, tips, tricks and formulae, but I was hoping that someone was keeping a list...

Comment: @Him There's not really much more to it, and the "plan for data collection will satisfy the assumptions of the statistical test that you plan to use" is, IMHO, too much detail already. There is more to the analysis than the statistical test, and these assumptions are pretty much the essence of the work, ergo, highly field-specific. If you specifically wanted a list of examples where something goes wrong at different stages of the analysis, sorry, I don't keep such a list. I normally do cover a few things like sample sizes, skewed distributions, p-hacking, show them spurious correlations...

Comment: But past that, it's hard to offer any generic advice while also not making it a full advanced class on statistics. I have a couple of such lists bookmarked [example one](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S188319581000112X?via%3Dihub) [example two](https://www.producttalk.org/2014/09/the-14-most-common-hypothesis-testing-mistakes-product-teams-make-and-how-to-avoid-them/), but not sure how much are they applicable to your situation.